# SAS Grid Validation error

Tags: sas

I am getting the following error message:

"Objspawn was unable to launch the server SASApp - Workspace Server due to the server launch exceeding the specified wait time. 
Failed to start the server"

This is a grid environment, and the new application servers created - (for example SASAppVS, created for the Visual Statistics use) - work fine. I am new to the grid environment. So, any help regarding this would be appreciated.

more on [SAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAS_%28software%29)

Comment: heavy load on the server perhaps?  This is a good question for SAS Tech Support. http://support.sas.com

Comment: Have you contacted the SAS administrators of your grid?